# How to dynamically update the label of a menu contributed to the org.eclipse.ui.menus extension

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

My eclipse plugin contributes a menu to the main menu. In it, is a sub-menu (`selection`) which in turn has some child elements (`items`). I would like to programmatically update the label of `selection` based on the selected item underneath. (see below)

```
    File   MyMenu   Edit
    ─────┬─────────────────────┬──────────────────
         │ Selection: Item B  >│┌───────────┐
         └─────────────────────┘│   Item A  │
                                │ v Item B  │
                                │   Item C  │
                                └───────────┘
```

Using the command framework I was able to implement most of it (see below), but I can't figure out how to programmatically append the `selection` sub-menu with the text of its selected child.

Below are the relevant parts of the extensions to the plugin xml:

```xml
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
      <command
            defaultHandler="menu_selector.DoSelectHandler"
            id="command.do_select"
            name="Select Option">
         <commandParameter
               id="command.do_select.option_value"
               name="Option Value"
               optional="false">
         </commandParameter>
         <commandParameter
               id="command.do_select.persisted_value"
               name="Persisted Value"
               optional="false">
         </commandParameter>
      </command>
    </extension>

    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
         <menu
               label="MyMenu">
            <menu
                  id="menu.selection"
                  label="Selection: ">
               <dynamic
                     class="menu_selector.ItemsProvider"
                     id="items">
               </dynamic>
            </menu>
         </menu>
      </menuContribution>
    </extension>
```

In the class `ItemsProvider`, I implemented `getContributionItems()` to populate the `items` dynamic sub-menu with `do_select` commands.

The class `DoSelectHandler` implements `IElementUpdater`. The commands framework calls its `updateElement(UIElement element, Map parameters)` method for all commands in the `items` dynamic menu right before it displays it. I use it to call `setChecked(true)` on the relevant element parameter to set the `v` character in front of the selected item in the `items` dynamic menu.

This would also be a logical route to update the `selection` menu, but I can't see how I can accomplish that. Setting the `commandId` on the `selection` menu doesn't make the commands framework call `updateElement()` with the `selection` menu as its element parameter.

Does anybody have an idea how to go around this?

Comment: Thanks for the edits Yan! It's a lot clearer now.

Comment: If you want to notify users about a comment write their name with a "@" in the front, like this: @emdeesee . I saw this comment by pure luck. BTW, you're welcome :)

Comment: @Yan B. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get more control with specifing your own class for menu contribution

```xml
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            class="org.examples.menu.VeryDynamicMenuFactory"
            locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?after=additions">
      </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

The class should extend  `org.eclipse.ui.menus.ExtensionContributionFactory`